# how do i input string in Linked List

Tags: c, string, linked-list

im curently working on linked list but to input some string ive veeb trying several ways to do it , i dont know what makes them error

this is my current code

```
struct barang{
    char namabarang[30];
    int hargabarang;
    int idbarang;
    struct barang* next;
};
struct barang *head;

void input()
{
    struct barang *ptr;
    char nama[30];
    int harga,id;

    ptr = (struct barang*)malloc(sizeof(struct barang *));
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\n\tOVERFLOW!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\n\tSilahkan Masukan\n");
        printf("\tNama barang  : ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]",nama);
        strcpy(ptr ->namabarang,nama);
        ptr-> next = head;
        head = ptr;
        printf("\n\tData Berhasil Disimpan di NODE awal!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `fflush( stdin )` is undefined behavior as far as standard C is concerned. That `scanf()` call is also UB waiting to happen; try `fgets()` instead.

Comment: "OVERFLOW" is not a particularly useful error message to describe a malloc failure.  Indeed, I don't see how anyone would interpret that error message accurately.  And error messages belong on stderr.  eg `fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");` or (preferrably) `perror("malloc");`

Comment: You never consume any newlines.  So all scanf after the first consume no data.  *Always* check the return value of scanf.  You will see that it is returning zero,  so nama remains uninitialized, and the `strcpy` are all undefined behavior.

Comment: On a side note, the `strcpy` are totally unnecessary.  Just have scanf write directly to `ptr->namabarang`.  And put a limit on the scanf: `if( scanf(" %29[^\n]", ptr->namabrang ) == 1 ){ ... }`

Comment: Side note: the casts like `(struct barang*)` before `malloc` are useless. They have no purpose.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(struct barang *))` should be `malloc(sizeof(struct barang))`.

Comment: @oka I prefer `ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr)` to tie the type to the allocation.

Comment: @Neil As do I, but here I gave the simplest correct change possible that illustrates the error clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You are never consuming any newlines, so all the `scanf` after the first are not reading any data.  Probably the simplest solution is to modify the scanf to be:

```
if( scanf(" %29[^\n]", ptr->namabarang ) != 1 ){
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

By writing directly to `ptr->namabrang`, you can omit the `strcpy`.  Adding the leading whitespace in the format specifier will cause subsequent `scanf` to consume the newlines, but will also trim any leading white space.  If that is a problem, you should *STOP USING SCANF*.  You should not be using scanf in any case, but that's another discussion.  Also, adding the width modifier will prevent a buffer overflow.